# how to get the exact row using query

Tags: mysql, joomla

I want to get the exact row from the following data

```
id   name     groupid

1    robert   1,2
2    henry    11,12
```

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE groupid LIKE '%1%'
```

Above query will return both row
How to get the first row ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming `groupid` is a `varchar` column having ids stored as comma seperated list you can try this:

```
select * from table where CONCAT(',',groupid,',') LIKE '%,1,%';
```

or better approach would be to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in mysql:

```
select * from table where find_in_set(1, groupid);
```

Comment: if the row will `1    robert   2,1` & `2    henry    11,12`

Comment: This answer gets more correct every time I look at it ... (by which I mean, nice edits.)

Comment: Sorry Omesh...thats my mistake..i tried with `\`table\``.. gave output

Answer (score 4):

You could use  [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', groupid)
```

But as suggestion, you should not save data like this.

Answer (score 0):

To get an *exact row* from a database table, just specify all the fields:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1
AND name = 'robert'
AND groupid = '1,2'
```

Or, assuming `id` is the unique primary key, you can just use that:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE '%1%' will return all the results which contain 1. Use @lc solution WHERE groupid = '1,2' to get only result with that specific id.